# VS2017 C++ debugger skipping lines of code

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-debugging

I did a quick search and found nothing similar to this question. Maybe I don't know how to search for this one, sorry.

I recently moved to VS2017 (community version) from VS2015. I'm involved in a project where I develop in C++. Sometimes I need to debug, as usual.

I noticed the debugger on VS2017 doesn't work as it did on 2015 version. I don't know if it's a configuration problem.

The problem is that Step over, Step Into, Step Out don't work the expected way (execute a code line and move to the next one/etc). I uploaded here some screenshots of the debugger behaviour: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3V1R5.jpg

Just pressing F10 (Step Over), the debugger moves that way (line 222->239->242->244->248->244->248->254), skipping code lines in between, even moving forwards and backwards.

As it is seen in the other images, the breakpoint works alright, and there are 2 types of "debug line indicators", with different message.

How can I set the VS options to get the wanted debug?

Comment: Are you debugging in Debug or Release build?  Stepping through a Release build is going to do crazy stuff as the executable no longer exactly matches the code you wrote.

Comment: Are you debugging optimized code? If yes, then it's not so strange since the compilers optimizer may have seriously rearranged the code and dropped some of it entirely. For a reliable debug experience, debug a unoptimized debug build.

Comment: @NathanOliver thank you for your idea. I use a batch file to move the dlls around my PC, and temporarily I did change from debug to release dlls there. So I was building in debug mode, but was not executing the debug dlls. **Now it is fixed**, thank you very much :-) https://imgur.com/a/RgzhIMB

Comment: @user0123 Glad to know your issue has been solved. You can add the details of it as an answer,which can be beneficial to other community members. It can be easier for them to search the solution.

Answer (score 2):

When optimizations are enabled, the compiler is free to optimize away certain pieces of code. For instance, performing a redundant assignment. However, even with all optimizations disabled, the C++ standard mandates certain optimizations (e.g. some forms of RVO object initialization).

From the code you show, I'd say it's likely that the compiler is reordering the initialization of the (many) local variables and also perhaps aliasing them from their sources instead of copying them. This would conceivably be done to reduce memory usage inside the function and is safe so long as you don't take the address of the local variable nor make a reference to it.

Additionally, though the compiler guarantees that your code will function as if it were executed sequentially (as you wrote it), most compilers (with optimizations enabled) will reorder things that it can guarantee will not break your code for efficiency reasons. This is typically done to minimize memory accesses, enable vectorization, or for hardware-specific instruction pipelining reasons.